# How to find Object Permissions of unknown SObject?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger

I need to find the object or field level permission of unknow SObject property

```
public void updateRecord(SObject obj) {

    if(Schema.sObjectType.SObject.isUpdateable())
    update obj;

}
```

How to get input obj permission?

Answer (score 2):

You can just describe it:

```
if(obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the lightning reply.